# In Jenkins pipeline some environment variables are having null value

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenknsfile I want to check CHANGE_AUTHOR, CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL and some more variables. But when I run it shows null value.

Code snip from Jenkinsfile
Code:

```
if (env.CHANGE_ID){
echo "CHANGE_ID : ${env.CHANGE_ID}"
echo "CHANGE_URL : ${env.CHANGE_URL}"
echo "CHANGE_TITLE : ${env.CHANGE_TITLE}"
echo "CHANGE_AUTHOR : ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR}"
echo "CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME : ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME}"
echo "CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL : ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL}"
echo "CHANGE_TARGET : ${env.CHANGE_TARGET}"
echo "BRANCH_NAME : ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
...
...
```

Output of pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_ID : 69
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_URL : null
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_TITLE : Generic jenkinsfile
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_AUTHOR : null
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME : null
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL : null
[Pipeline] echo
CHANGE_TARGET : null
[Pipeline] echo
BRANCH_NAME : PR-69
```

How can I get the variables value which shows null?

Comment: echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env') should print all env vars, maybe that can help you see what you are working with. And of course you can pipe it to grep --> sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env | grep CHANGE')

Comment: @herm it executes successfully but -
1. In Push event does not print Any change related variables.
2. In Pull Request event it only prints (CHANGE_TITLE and CHANGE_ID) variables related to change.

Expected variables :
CHANGE_URL, CHANGE_TITLE, CHANGE_AUTHOR, CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME, CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL, CHANGE_TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a multibranch pipeline job? Those variables are only available in multibranch. See the *env* section on this page of your Jenkins instance:

http://Jenkins.server.url/pipeline-syntax/globals